# Is there a way to uniquely identifiy user in Windows 8 (WinRT)?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am developing a magazine reading app for Windows 8 (Metro). All the magazine issues should be buyable using in-app purchases. I need to uniquely identify the user that makes the purchases. If I pair the purchases with the device id (Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken) and the user uses the app on multiple devices he will have to buy the content for each device again. I do not want that. Is there a way to uniquely identifiy user (and pair him with the bought content in the publishers system)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation` allows you access to the current user's info.  You can also use `Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId` namespace if you need to authenticate them against Live and get additional info, with user consent.

Comment: Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation only gives you the Name+Surname which are not unique. DisplayName may contain email if Name+Surname are not provided but I cannot depend on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the App Specific Hardware ID: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431

Comment: I'm after the same as Igor is and I have seen responses like yours many places. A hardware is not a unique identifier for a user, as he/she is like to have more than one device. Therefore we need to unique identification for the particular user. On Windows Phone you can get what we need via UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID")

Comment: I don't mean to be rude here :) Just had to put this in a comment, as it's not really a answer to his question.